# Parallel AJAX request without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to fetch multiple parallel request with single callback, just like jQuery "when"

```
$.when(ajax1, ajax2).done(callback)
```

I don't want to call the second ajax call after ajax1 is completed, I want ajax2 and ajax2 to be requested same time and than the callback when both are completed.

I'm looking for plain javascript instead of jQuery for such implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a method to make the request that will return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

This could be simply using [the fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or [wrapping XMLHttpRequest with a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises).

Put the two promises in an array and pass it to [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```
Promise.all([ fetch("http://example.com"), fetch("http://example.net") ])
    .then(array => console.log(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use async/ await with Promise.all to achieve that:

```
async function getAll() {
  // waits untill all resposnes are resolved
  const data = await Promise.all([
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(response =>
      response.json()
    ),
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2').then(response =>
      response.json()
    ),
  ]);
  // returns array of resolved data from fetch
  console.log(data);
}

getAll()
```

Answer (score -2):

You can replace `done` to `then` Method

```
$.when( ajax1 , ajax2 ).then(function() {
    // success ajax1, success ajax 2
});
```

Comment: This will throw an error because `$` isn't defined. The question very clearly was asking for a solution which does not use jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using jQuery.